# Prove $\oint_\Gamma\vec\nabla f\cdot d\vec{r}=0$ when $\Gamma$ is the unit circle

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

I have encountered a statement in my book which didn't seem quite right to me. It was written exactly like this:

> Let $f(x,y):\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function such that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ are continuous functions for all $(x,y)\neq(0,0)$, and let $\Gamma$ be the unit circle, centered at $(0,0)$. Then:
>
> $$\oint_\Gamma\vec\nabla f\cdot d\vec{r}=0$$

I tried to sit down and think why is this statement true. You all must have encountered before the infamous vector field:

$$\vec{F}=\left(-\frac{y}{x^2+y^2},\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}\right)$$

This vector field is the gradient of the function $f(x,y)=\arctan(\frac yx)$ if I remember correctly. This function is of course problematic on the $y$ axis. However, I assume you can define $f$ on the $y$ axis, apart from the point $(0,0)$, such that the partial derivatives of $f$ would exist and also be continuous there (I'm not sure about that, but the fact that the parital derivatives are clearly continuous for every point but $(0,0)$ has led me to that assumption).

So $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ are indeed continuous for all $(x,y)\neq(0,0)$, but $\displaystyle \oint_\Gamma\vec\nabla f\cdot d\vec{r} $ would be equal to $\pm2 \pi$ (depends on the orientation of $\Gamma$).

To conclude, I would like to know whether my example disproves the above statement, or maybe it is wrong. If it's not correct, I would be glad to hear why, and in addition, have a proof of the statement. I thought of many ways to prove it - using Green's Theorem and the fact that $\vec\nabla\times\vec\nabla f\equiv0$, stating $\vec\nabla f$ is a conservative vector field (since it is derived from a gradient of a scalar potential function) and more; But of course I wouldn't go there before I know why my example is incorrect.

Thanks!

Comment: No, the vector field $F$ is not the gradient of any function $f$. You say "I would like to know whether my example disproves the above statement", but you haven't given any example! You know $\arctan(y/x)$ doesn't work  - you say you assume it can be fixed somehow. You haven't given an example until you specify exactly how you intend to modify $\arctan(y/x)$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I understand. Do you know how to prove the statement?

Comment: In fact the integral of $\nabla f$ over any closed curve is $0$. This follows just from the _definition_ of the integral (plus the chain rule and the fundamental theorem of calculus).

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich "No, the vector field  is not the gradient of any function" - prove it please.

Comment: The integral of  any gradient over any closed curve is $0$. The integral of $F$ over the unit circle is not $0$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich consider $\Omega = \mathbb{R^2} \setminus \{(0, 0)\}$. So $F$ is not gradient of $\arctan(\frac yx)$ on $\Omega$? Probably you have said a lot of excess. I agree that it's easy to prove the statement using the definition. I also agree that $\arctan(\frac yx)$ is not counterexample, because it's not even continuous. But you are too rude to explain it.

Comment: @RRL No, my comment was not for you, sorry. No, the origin is not the problem. We're talking about $f\in C^1(\Omega)$, where $\Omega=\Bbb R^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$. There does not exist $f\in C^1(\Omega)$ with $F=\nabla f$ in $\Omega$. Give me a minute to type a proof.

Comment: @EugeneSirkiza Earlier I was confused about who said what. To answer your question, in case it's not yet clear: No, $F$ is certainly not the gradient of $f=\arctan(y/x)$ in $\Omega$.  It can't possibly be - as you point out yourself, $f$ is not even continuous in $\Omega$; in fact $\nabla x$ _does  not exist_ in $\Omega$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lucky you, the appearance of a totally wrong answer persuaded me to post a  complete solution.

> > **Fundamental Theorem of Calculus for line integrals:** Suppose $\Omega\subset\Bbb R^2$ is open and $f\in C^1(\Omega)$. If $\gamma:[0,1]\to\Omega$ is a $C^1$ curve  then $\int_\gamma\nabla f\cdot dr=f(\gamma(1))-f(\gamma(0))$.

(Hence if $\gamma$ is a *closed* curve (meaning $\gamma(1)=\gamma(0)$) the integral is $0$. With $\Omega=\Bbb R^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$ and $\gamma(t)=(\cos(2\pi t),\sin(2\pi t))$ this proves the result you ask about; in particular what happens at the origin doesn't  matter.)

Proof, even though it must be in the book: By definition, if $F$ is a vector field then $$\int_\gamma F\cdot dr=\int_0^1F(\gamma(t))\cdot\gamma'(t)\,dt.$$Now suppose that $F=\nabla f$, and set $$g(t)=f(\gamma(t)).$$The chain rule shows that $$F(\gamma(t))\cdot \gamma'(t)=g'(t),$$so $$\int_\gamma F\cdot dr=\int_0^1g'(t)\,dt=g(1)-g(0).$$

> > **Corollary:** If $\Omega=\Bbb R^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$ and $F$ is the infamous vector field mentioned in the question there does not exist $f\in C^1(\Omega)$ with $F=\nabla f$.

(Indeed, in the language used in calculus books, $F$ is the standard example of a vector field which is closed but not exact.)

Comment: Great! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

As $f(x,y) = \arctan \frac{y}{x}$ is not defined along the y-axis, the function is not continuous and the partial derivatives do not exist when $x = 0.$

Even if the equations $\nabla f = (\frac{-y}{x^2+y^2}, \frac{x}{x^2+y^2})$ don't indicate that there is a problem, the partial derivatives do not exist when $x = 0$, and they are not, in fact, continuous.

Comment: "Even if the equations ... don't indicate there's a problem..." strikes me as misleading or missing the point. That equation is simply not true for $x=0$, so it's irrelevant,

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I made a small change to the language, that might be better.  But, those are the equations one gets if one mechanically applies the differentiation rules, without thinking critically about the discontinuities.   So, I don't think it is misleading to say that those are the equations one gets.  They just don't tell the whole story by themselves.